# Как сделать приватную WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

У меня есть простой апи контроллер, который я показал выше.
Но каждый сможет прописать (пример - не тыкайте)"https://www.example.com/api/values/delete/3" - и удалит с бд елемент с айди 3.
Как сделать закрытую апишку, чтоб не смог каждый ее заюзать, а только я для своих других программ?

Comment: Добавить аутентификацию и авторизацию.

Comment: как? есть ссылка?

Comment: CustomAuthorizeAttribute + config.Filters.Add(new CustomAuthorizeAttribute());

Comment: Есть много разных способов, как реализовать авторизацию/аутентификацию. Все зависит от требований. Неплохое начало для изучения тут https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security